# Create a link to a private file from just a file id?

Tags: 8, files

I am building a controller that returns a rendered HTML Response object to an AJAX request in the theme. I need to display a button that contains a link to a private file. I tried to mimic what the System module does, but this code seems like a lot just to generate an accessible private file path:

```
  /**
   * Returns a render element for the download paper link.
   *
   * @param int $id
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Link
   */
  protected function getDownloadLink(int $id) : Link {
    /** @var \Drupal\file\Entity\File $file */
    $file = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('file')->load($id);

    $url = Url::fromRoute('system.private_file_download',
      ['filepath' => str_replace('/system/files/', '', $file->createFileUrl())],
      [
        'absolute' => TRUE,
        'path_processing' => FALSE,
        'attributes' => [
          'class' => $this->button_classes,
        ]
      ]
    );

    return Link::fromTextAndUrl('Download Paper Anyway', $url);
  }
```

Is there a simpler way of obtaining a file path from the file object to satisfy the route parameter here?

Comment: You could do `Url::fromUri(file_create_url($p->field_resource_file->entity->uri->value)` Instead of your `Url::fromRoute('system.private_file_download',
      ['filepath' => str_replace('/system/files/', '', $file->createFileUrl())]` this code has the benefit of working for public or private files

Comment: Yeah, that works.